# How to Improve performance of nested ng-repeat in Angulajs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling in my AngularJs project and I am using nested ng-repeat and binding the data by JAVA API, the data return by service is huge so the performance is getting very low. I have Googled for the different solution nothing is working for me.

[Use of Track Id](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)

Controller Code

```
var developerController = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$window',
'developerData', '$route', '$timeout', '$compile', '$routeParams',
function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $window, developerData, $route, $timeout, $compile, $routeParams) {
    globalModel.showSpinner();
    $scope.developerData = developerData.retData[0];
    // $scope.homeData = homeData.retData;

    $scope.perpages = 10;
    $scope.hasReadMore = false;
    $scope.windowScrolled = false;
    var hasPageInUrl = $location.url().indexOf('page=') != -1;
    $scope.pageParm = parseInt($routeParams.page);
    $scope.hasPageInUrl = hasPageInUrl;

    // alert($scope.hasPageInUrl);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#abtDeveloperContent").html($scope.developerData.abtDeveloper);
    });

    $scope.isMobileAppBanner = function(index) {
        index = index + 1;
        return ((index % 6) / 100 == 0);
    };
    if ($scope.hasPageInUrl == true && angular.isNumber($scope.pageParm) == true) {
        $scope.currentPage = $scope.pageParm;
    } else {
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    }
    $scope.totalPages = Math.ceil($scope.developerData.projects.length / $scope.perpages);
    if ($scope.currentPage > $scope.totalPages) {
        var newurl = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path();
        window.location.href = newurl;

    } else {
        globalModel.showSpinner();
        $scope.developerPaginatedData = $scope.developerData.projects;
        $scope.developerPaginatedData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.totalProjects - a.totalProjects
        });
        $scope.filteredProjects = [];
        $scope.isMobile = $rootScope.isMobile;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        if ($scope.isMobile == true) {
            $scope.maxSize = 3;
        }
        $scope.begin = 0;
        $scope.end = 0;

        $rootScope.approvedCities = appConfig.approvedCities;

        $scope.numPages = function() {
            return Math.ceil($scope.developerData.projects.length / $scope.perpages);
        };
        $scope.FlagshipImage = '';

        /* Pagination Logic */

        if ($scope.isMobile == true || $rootScope.isFragment == true || hasPageInUrl == true) {
            $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
                //$scope.panIndiaDataArr = globalModel.doPaging($scope.panIndiaData,4);
                if ($scope.currentPage > $scope.totalPages || $scope.pageParm <= 1) {
                    var newurl = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path();
                    // window.location.href = newurl;
                }
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.perpages),
                    end = begin + $scope.perpages;
                $scope.filteredProjects = $scope.developerData.projects.slice(begin, end);
                console.log($scope.filteredProjects);
                $scope.developerDataArr = globalModel.doPaging($scope.filteredProjects, 6);
                //console.log($scope.developerDataArr);

                $timeout(function() {
                    $(".dev_ui_bootstarp_pagination").each(function(i, paginationlink) {
                        var pageno = $(this).attr("pageno");
                        var isdisabled = $(this).parent().hasClass("disabled");

                        if (isdisabled == false && pageno > 1 && parseInt($(this).text()) > 1) {
                            $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + pageno);
                        }

                        if (pageno == 1) {
                            $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path());
                        }

                        if ($(this).text() == "<<") {
                            var firstpageno = $(".panindia_pagination > ul > li:first").next().find("a").attr("pageno");
                            if (firstpageno > 1) {
                                var prevno = parseInt(firstpageno) - 1;
                                $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + prevno);
                            } else {
                                $(this).removeAttr("href");
                                $(this).parent().addClass("disabled");
                            }
                        }

                        if ($(this).text() == ">>") {
                            var lastpageno = $(".panindia_pagination > ul > li:last").prev().find("a").attr("pageno");
                            if (lastpageno < $scope.totalPages) {
                                var nextno = parseInt(lastpageno) + 1;
                                $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + nextno);
                            } else {
                                $(this).removeAttr("href");
                                $(this).parent().addClass("disabled");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        }


    }
    if ($scope.isMobile == false && hasPageInUrl == false && $rootScope.isFragment == false) {


        $scope.loadMore = function() {
            // alert("load more called");

            var offset = $('#dev_loadmore').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (offset <= window.innerHeight && ((parseInt($scope.currentPage) + 1) <= $scope.totalPages || $scope.currentPage == 1)) {
                if ($scope.end > $scope.developerData.projects.length) {
                    return false;
                }
                $scope.begin = 0;
                $scope.end = $scope.end + $scope.perpages;
                $scope.windowScrolled = true;
                $("#dev_loadmore").overlay();
                $scope.filteredProjects = $scope.developerData.projects.slice($scope.begin, $scope.end);
                $scope.developerDataArr = globalModel.doPaging($scope.filteredProjects, 6);
                $("#dev_loadmore").overlayout();
                $scope.windowScrolled = false;
            }
            $timeout(function() {
                $(".dev_ui_bootstarp_pagination").each(function(i, paginationlink) {
                    var pageno = $(this).attr("pageno");
                    var isdisabled = $(this).parent().hasClass("disabled");

                    if (isdisabled == false && pageno > 1 && parseInt($(this).text()) > 1) {
                        $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + pageno);
                    }

                    if (pageno == 1) {
                        $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path());
                    }

                    if ($(this).text() == "<<") {
                        var firstpageno = $(".panindia_pagination > ul > li:first").next().find("a").attr("pageno");
                        if (firstpageno > 1) {
                            var prevno = parseInt(firstpageno) - 1;
                            $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + prevno);
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("href");
                            $(this).parent().addClass("disabled");
                        }
                    }

                    if ($(this).text() == ">>") {
                        var lastpageno = $(".panindia_pagination > ul > li:last").prev().find("a").attr("pageno");
                        if (lastpageno < $scope.totalPages) {
                            var nextno = parseInt(lastpageno) + 1;
                            $(this).attr("href", $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + nextno);
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("href");
                            $(this).parent().addClass("disabled");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        };

    }

    /* formation of previous and next url in html source ccode */

    var prev_rel = "";
    var next_rel = "";

    if ($scope.currentPage == 1) {
        next_rel = "<link rel='next' href='" + $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + ($scope.currentPage + 1) + "'>";
    }

    if ($scope.currentPage > 1 && $scope.currentPage <= $scope.totalPages) {
        if ($scope.currentPage == 2) {
            prev_rel = "<link rel='prev' href='" + $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "'>";
        } else {
            prev_rel = "<link rel='prev' href='" + $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + ($scope.currentPage - 1) + "'>";
        }
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.totalPages) {
            next_rel = "<link rel='next' href='" + $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + $location.path() + "?page=" + ($scope.currentPage + 1) + "'>";
        }
    }


    $("head > link[rel='prev'],head > link[rel='next']").remove();
    if ($scope.totalPages > 1) {
        $("head").append(prev_rel);
        $("head").append(next_rel);
    }

    //console.log($scope.developerData.abtDeveloper);



    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            developerUI.init();
            $('html,body,.listingTilesBox').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
            globalModel.hideSpinner("from developerController - line no 31");
        });
    });


    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {

            $rootScope.pagelevel = 'HOME';
            $("#footerlink_container").html('');
            angular.element(document.getElementById('footerlink_container')).append(
                $compile("<footer-data></footer-data>")($rootScope));
            $rootScope.global.setFooterData();

            if ($rootScope.city == undefined) {
                $rootScope.seopagelevel = 'PAN-INDIA-BUILDER';
            }

            $("#footerlink_seocontainer").html('');
            angular.element(document.getElementById('footerlink_seocontainer')).append(
                $compile("<seo-footer-data></seo-footer-data>")($rootScope));
            $rootScope.global.setSeoFooterData();

            developerUI.init();
            var height = $('#abtDeveloperContent').height();
            if (height > 200) {
                $scope.hasReadMore = true;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".readmoreSection .readMoreBox").off("click");
                    $(".readmoreSection .readMoreBox").on("click", function() {
                        $(".readmoreSection").toggleClass("fullHeight");
                    });

                });
            }

            $($("#abtDeveloperContent").find("ul li")).each(function(i, desc_li) {
                var lihtml = $(this).html();
                $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-circle fs-10' aria-hidden='true'></i> " + lihtml);
            });


            globalModel.hideSpinner("from developerController - line no 104");
        });
    });
}
```

];

Html for binding Data

```
<div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
<div ng-repeat="projectPaginationData in developerDataArr" ng-init="rowIndex = $index" ng-if="(isMobile==false && isFragment==false && hasPageInUrl == false)">
    <div ng-repeat="project in projectPaginationData" ng-if="$index >= begin && $index <= end">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <project-info ng-model="project" ng-init="project.type = 'INDIA'" show-units="true" />
        </div>
        <deal-app-banner ng-if="isMobileAppBanner($index)"></deal-app-banner>

        <deal-lead-banner ng-if="$index == 1 && rowIndex == 1 "></deal-lead-banner>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="projectPaginationData in developerDataArr" ng-init="rowIndex = $index" ng-if="(isMobile==true || isFragment==true || hasPageInUrl == true)">
    <div ng-repeat="project in projectPaginationData">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <project-info ng-model="project" ng-init="project.type = 'INDIA'" show-units="true" />
        </div>
        <deal-app-banner ng-if="isMobileAppBanner($index)"></deal-app-banner>

        <deal-lead-banner ng-if="$index == 1 && currentPage == 2"></deal-lead-banner>
    </div>
</div>
```

loadMore() function is for enabling infinite scrolling.

Please help me.

Comment: Mustache could be a good solution (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) I've used when I had nested iterations and the results are good

Answer (score 0):

use `limitTo` filter. Here is doc [Angular limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

```
ng-repeat="d in data | limitTo:numberOfItemsDisplayed"
```

Comment: limitTo will restrict my output to only that limit